# Is there a tag like verbatim, except you can set it to dirty?

Tags: ajax, jsp, jsf, custom-tags

What I would like is something like following:

```
<f:verbatim>
<%
out.println("<span id='test'>Data</span>");
%>
</f:verbatim>
```

I would like the out.println code to be rerun by ajax.  However, when I set that form to dirty, the out.println is not rerun.

Is there a way around this, short of using a custom tag?

What I need is a tag, like

```
<f:writeAsHTML value="#{bean.HTMLproducer}"/>
```

Is there already a tag like that in myfaces or basic JSF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it in `f:verbatim` without that *scriptlet*

```
<f:verbatim>
    <span id="test">Data</span>
</f:verbatim>
```

Or just print it plain (only possible on JSF 1.2 or newer)

```
<span id="test">Data</span>
```

Or use `h:outputText` since it renders a `<span>` anyway

```
<h:outputText id="test" value="Data" />
```

Or use `h:outputText escape="false"` if the HTML comes from a bean property

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.html}" escape="false" />
```

---

As per your functional requirement which reads like

> *I would like the out.println code to be rerun by ajax*

The problem needs to be solved elsewhere. Are you using JSF 1.x or 2.x? Regardless, you should utilize JSF-provided Ajax components like RichFaces' Ajax4jsf components or JSF 2.0's `<f:ajax>` components which offers a `render` attribute to trigger re-rendering of JSF components.

Comment: To me escape="false" basically does the same thing as out.println, only it is binded and rerun by ajax.  This is exactly what I need, thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry if I proposed too many suggestions, but your question is also not really that clear and to-the-point. It's too high-level, the functional requirement is vague and the terminology is not entirely straight.

Comment: I would seriously hire you if I had the chance. Sadly, I am entry level.